# Linux Mint Live & Ubuntu ISO's failing to boot (failed to execute /init)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Tested ISO's:

- `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64`
- `linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit`
- `linuxmint-20.1-cinnamon-64bit`
- `linuxmint-20.2-cinnamon-64bit`

All of these images fail to boot with `No working init found` on one specific system (i tested the images and usb stick on other systems, there they booted fine)

I had also extracted the `initrd.lz` file and verified that an `/init` script is available

Somehow about ~7 months ago, i could install image `linuxmint-20.1-cinnamon-64bit` successfully on the system, but now i need to reinstall the system to have an clean install (same iso (verified with sha256sum and option `Integrity Check`), same USB stick, same system trying to run), but now all of these images fail with the same error

I also tried adding the boot option `init=/init` which failed with `Requested init /init failed (error -2)`

Screenshot (literally) with the normal live option:
[image: kernel Panic Screenshot]

I am not experienced enough to make my own installer (or actually to extract the iso and make it bootable in hybrid mode, while not breaking the installer itself)

System (where its failing):

- Intel Atom D425 (in 64bit mode)
- 2GB DDR 3 ram (tested that nothing is corrupt)
- BIOS supporting UEFI (though no specific partition boot is available)

Note: i tried all 3 options in the mint grub menu (normal live, compat live, oem install), but none of them worked

Note: nothing physical can have happened to the system and not really any "software" changes either, because since the last mentioned successfully install, it has been sitting in an shelf without being powered on in the meantime

PS: i also tried `manjaro-kde-21.0.5-minimal-210519-linux510` which failed at pacman-keyring because of an invalid opcode

Comment: I have this issue with debian testing and stable 11.5.0 netinstall iso that i download it from debian site now with kernel 6 and can't solve it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some more things, and finally noticed that when not using "Boot Menu (F10)", it suddenly booted without any problems into the usb (it even started used the UEFI mode, which with F10 it did not)

for anyone encountering this issue, the system that made these problems were:

- CPU: `Intel Atom CPU D425 @ 1.80GHz`
- BIOS: `MWPNT10N.86A` (full: `MWPNT10N.86A.0083.2011.0524.1600`)

<strike>(just make sure the first device in the boot order is the install device, in my case USB, with the option `Boot USB Devices First` to `Enable`)</strike>

EDIT: for me the `Boot USB Devices First` did absolutely nothing and changing the boot order for the USB did also not work, so i had to either remove the hdd, which was not an option, so i had to boot into the working system and remove boot partitions / flags from there (`dd bs=64M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,hasezoey, for asking this question.  It gave me the incentive I needed to jump back into my own scenario to salvage several machines!

UPDATE:  I achieved success in the following manner, and maybe you can, too:

Learn from https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/usb-partition-manager.html that booting from partitions on a thumb drive is best from smaller ones, at least less than 64 GB.

1. "clean" the USB thumb drive from all partitions.  I think this step was critical.  The way I did this was on an older Windows 7 box.  This is step 5 suggested at https://www.eassos.com/blog/how-to-restore-usb-drive-back-to-full-capacity/
2. From that same page, continue to execute the next two steps.  They create a primary MBR partition and format it as fat32.  Avoid the temptation to use an overly large partition size that might be available if you're using the latest Windows 10.
3. Rufus utility will be used to put the ISO on the thumb drive because Rufus will also grab the linux system files for you.  First, I suggest you download the ISO file yourself because Rufus probably doesn't offer the ISO you'll want.  I suggest checkmarking the Rufus box about installing a Rufus MBR.  Whether Rufus marks the partition as bootable is unknown by me, but I did not need to do it explicitly anywhere in the process.

Previous answer:
[Explaining the “No working init found." boot hang message](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/init.html), Authors Andreas Mohr  and Cristian Souza  imply that there is a sequence of several steps that ALL must succeed to get past that specific error.  That page ends with the implication that all the causes of that specific fault are not fully characterized.

Back when iso file sizes were small enough to fit on CDROM and before UEFI, this problem didn't exist.  So BIOS/CMOS settings and USB partitions (are more than one needed? GPT/MBR?) need to be understood.

I question whether the number of possible causes of this problem are even being reduced with each new year, new manufacturer UEFI, new GRUB techniques, etc, etc.  I wonder if a Pandora's Box might have been opened by entering the latest door or two into this booting realm, since I, too, have been plagued with this error message lately and not able to find any comprehensive resource covering the numerous possible configurations.  Good luck!

That said, what do you mean by "same USB stick" in more detail?  Has it been used in the meantime?  Have any files been changed on it?  I only ask to shape your initial post, not that I have any solid idea so far.

Comment: by `same USB stick` i reffered to "same usb stick hardware", yes the contents changed in the meantime, but the hardware is the same, and the iso is verified before flash to be the same and also verified after flash (integrity check)

Comment: Per the resource above, my first step to troubleshoot mine will be: Add "debug" to the "append" line of the menu choice I will make at the USB boot menu: 
label live
  menu label Try <distro name>
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz quiet splash debug --

Comment: I changed my mind about troubleshooting because I was successful with one final attempt, as detailed above in this answer.

Comment: sorry to respond so late, but i tried again - this time trying to figure it out with 1080p@60 (instead of 1080@30), and with or without `debug`, the output is the same, i just noticed one message which could indicate *something*, being `Initramfs unpacking failed: junk within compressed archive`, but like i said earlier, the same usb and iso works on different machines (and the same iso worked earlier this year)

Comment: In your answer below you indicate you overwrote the /dev/sda with 64MB of 0's, which I would suggest that did the same thing as my step #1 above where I say I thought that step was critical.  So I'm even more convinced of that.  In my case, before I "cleaned" the partitions from the device, I noticed there were three partitions, only one (and the second one at that) had a file system.  So we might be saying that the best hope is for the USB drive to be free of any remnants of previous partitions to ensure that the ISO/install  partition is the very first one in the drive's partition table.

Comment: "In your answer below you indicate you overwrote the /dev/sda with 64MB of 0's" just to clarify, i did that on the *target machine* (to force it into loading the usb in uefi mode, see why in my answer) not on *the usb*